# working local pagination stopped working upon transfer to vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuejs3

I was practicing and learning about vuejs, specifically pagination.

I learn how to do it, and implemented it when I made the api calls in the component, then I moves the function to the actions in vuex, and mapped, them, now my pagination is not even showing up.

I wonder where I made the mistake ???

I have carefully paid attention to every single detail, and read about mutatioons, and actions, I do feel like I am doing everything right, I don't even have any mistakes showing up on the console. this is very wierd

```js
my postModule 

import axios from "axios";
export const postModule = {
    state: () => ({
        posts: [],
        page: 1,
        limit: 10,
        totalPages: 0,

    }),
    mutations: {
        setPosts(state, posts) {
            state.posts = posts;
        },
        setPage(state, page) {
            state.page = page;
        },
        setTotalPage(state, totalPages) {
            state.setTotalPage = totalPages
        },

    },
    actions: {
        async fetchPosts( {state, commit}) {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
                    params: {
                        _page: state.page,
                        _limit: state.limit,
                    },
                });
                commit('setTotalPage', Math.ceil(response.headers["x-total-count"] / state.limit));
                commit('setPosts', [...state.posts, ...response.data]);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        },

        async loadPosts({
            state,
            commit
        }) {
            try {
                commit('setPage', state.page + 1)
                setTimeout(async () => {
                    const response = await axios.get(
                        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
                            params: {
                                _page: state.page,
                                _limit: state.limit,
                            },
                        });
                    commit('setTotalPage', Math.ceil(response.headers["x-total-count"] / state.limit));
                    commit('setPosts', [...state.posts, ...response.data]);
                });

            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        },


    },
    namespaced: true,
}

<<<<<component >>>>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Page with the posts</h1>

    <post-list :posts="posts" />
  </div>
  <div class="page__wrapper">
    <div
      v-for="pageNumber in totalPages"
      :key="pageNumber"
      class="page"
      :class="{
        'current-page': page === pageNumber,
      }"
      @click="changePage(pageNumber)"
    >
      {{ pageNumber }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PostList from "@/components/PostList";
// import axios from 'axios';
import { mapState, mapMutations, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  components: { PostList },
  data() {
    return {
      // posts: [],
      // page: 1,
      // limit: 10,
      // totalPages: 0,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    changePage(pageNumber) {
      this.page = pageNumber;
      this.fetchPosts();
    },

    ...mapMutations({
      setPage: "setPage",
    }),
    ...mapActions({
      // loadPosts: "post/loadPosts",
      fetchPosts: "post/fetchPosts",
    }),
  },
  watch: {
    page() {
      this.fetchPosts();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchPosts();
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      posts: (state) => state.post.posts,
      page: (state) => state.post.page,
      limit: (state) => state.post.limit,
      totalPages: (state) => state.post.totalPages,
    }),
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.page__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px;
}
.page {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.current-page {
  border: 2px solid red;
  font-size: x-large;
}
</style>
```